# Javascript global onclick listener

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to register a global onclick listener that will fire anytime an element is clicked? Need to also get the id of that element.

Comment: `<body onclick="somefunction()">`

Comment: Can't modify the html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle a click anywhere in the page, even when a certain element stops the propagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054429/how-do-i-handle-a-click-anywhere-in-the-page-even-when-a-certain-element-stops)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(evnt){
    console.log(evnt.target.id);
});
```

Comment: What speaks against "addEventListener"? Which will probably translate to "window.addEventListener"?

Answer (score 3):

You can get id this way using javascript:

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {alert(event.target.id);}
```

```html
<div id="dID">div</div>
<button id="bId">Button</button>

<input type="text" id="txtId" class="txtclass" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> Check this code, I haves used it in my live project for tracking users
> behaviour.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event)=> { 
    console.log('emitting click events');
})

document.addEventListener('dblclick',(event)=>{
    console.log('emitting double click events');
} )

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event)=>{
    console.log('emitting right click events');
})

document.addEventListener('mouseenter',(event)=> {
   console.log("mouse enter, hovering started")
})

document.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event)=> {
console.log("hovering finished")
})
```