# Call function on every click (HTML includes frames)

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, frame, frameset

I have a function that should be called on EVERY click on the page.

So I tried to add an `EventListener` to the document:

```
 document.onclick = function() { /* Do Something */ };
```

but the problem is that there are many frames on my website

> (I know frames are evil and not supported in HTML 5)

So I tried to add an `EventListener` to every frame:

```
window.onload = window.setInterval(  
    function() {  
        frames = getFrames();  
        for(var i=0;i<frames.length;i++) 
            frames[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                //Do Something 
            }
    });
}, 50);

function getFrames() {
    var frameset = document.getElementsByTagName("FRAMESET")[1];
    var frame = frameset.getElementsByTagName("FRAME");
    return frame;
}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<frameset rows="100px,30px,*,5%">
    <frame src="topbar.php">
    <frame src="toolbar.php">
    <frameset cols="25%,40%,*%">
        <frame src="content.html>
        <frame src="content.html">
        <frame src="content.html">
    </frameset>
    <frame src="endbar.php">
</frameset>
```

Now working with:

```
window.onload = window.setInterval(
    function() {
        frames = getFrames();
        for(var i=0;i<frames.length;i++) 
            frames[i].contentDocument.onclick = 
                function() {
                    //Do Something
                    }
        };
}, 50);
```

Comment: it's not clear, you want an onclick event to happens every time you click on a tag without the onclick attribute?

Comment: I want to add the onclick event to the contentDocument of every frame to fire a function on every click.

Comment: it's allready answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054429/how-do-i-handle-a-click-anywhere-in-the-page-even-when-a-certain-element-stops

Comment: it should look like document.onclick = function() {}. Just as a EventListener for every frame.

Comment: it does not work because of the frames

Comment: what $('body').onclick?

Comment: If "frames are evil" (they are defiantly are) why you using them? Why not just include the toolbar topbar etc? Seems like a much easier problem to solve.

Comment: i will probably do that after i solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to me the only way to solve your problem is do somthing like this post:
[How do I handle a click anywhere in the page, even when a certain element stops the propagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054429/how-do-i-handle-a-click-anywhere-in-the-page-even-when-a-certain-element-stops)
and import the jquery libraries, if you don't have it allready

Comment: now i get a `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: i have write it:) do you have import the jquery library?

Comment: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: my advice is to not use the googleapis, but to download the apis and make a lib folder where to point, because if somthing change in the version there is thing that could work in different way from your expectation, despite this can you do a fiddle? or post the head of your html page?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE HTML>   
<html>  
<head>  
<script src="myScript.js"></script>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: ok in web page the order of your import have importance move the apis before the myscript.js

Comment: the function isn´t triggered

Comment: substitute your tag with body $('frameset').onclick

Comment: sorry $('frameset').click

Comment: where should i insert that?

Comment: script is now  `$("frameset").click( function() { console.log("function called"); });`

Comment: so still not working? shall we open a fiddle so we solve it together?