# Javascript - click anywhere event - CPM adverts

Tags: javascript

I have the CPM adverts on my web page - when user click anywhere on the page, the script is opening a poup with advert.
Is it possible to create a special script which will be click anywhere on the page without the user's knowledge?

Thanks.

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want to fraudulently generate clicks for your advertisements?

Comment: Even if you _could_ theoretically do it - which I doubt, chances are it would annoy your users to an unimaginably hight degree and it's probably against your advertisement platform's Terms of Service to fake clicks anyway.

Comment: I know but I want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this...

```js
  setTimeout(function(){
 document.getElementById('test').click();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='test' onclick='alert("ok");'>Check</div>
```

Comment: Yee! That's it! Can you tell me how to add an limit on this script - the script should click only once (now is clicking all the time).

Comment: @OP If your advertising platform allows to generate clicks _this_ easily then they deserve to be abused, but I would still stay away from doing it as it could get you in trouble if they find out.
@AnandSingh Why not `setTimeout` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question.

You can read how to handle click everywhere in the page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054429/how-do-i-handle-a-click-anywhere-in-the-page-even-when-a-certain-element-stops)
If you want to open the popup automatically, on document ready, you can click custom html element.

**EDIT**

You can generate fake click this way:

```
(function() {
  document.getElementById('yay').click();
})();
```

Comment: In following URL is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/M4teA/2/ It's working when you CLICKED on the background. I want create an script which will be click without the user's knowledge, so I do nothing and script "think" - I clicked on the webpage background.