# Maniupulate or Simulate Click on web page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onclick

I am trying to manipulate user click. Let say user clicked anywhere on the webpage but image in the DIV will get clicked.

I am trying with co-ordinate :

```
// Add an event listener to the document to listen for clicks
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  // Get the coordinates of the user's click
  var x = event.pageX;
  var y = event.pageY;

  // Calculate the coordinates of the new element based on the user's click
  var newX = x + 90; // adjust the value of newX as needed
  var newY = y + 150; // adjust the value of newY as needed

  // Get the element that you want to click on
  var element = document.elementFromPoint(newX, newY);

  // Create a new click event
  var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });

  // Dispatch the click event on the element
  element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

});
```

But this script did not worked. So, i thought maybe due to co-ordinate change based on screensize and viewport. So, i coded like this

```js
// Get a reference to the element you want to click on
var elementToClick = document.getElementById('my-element');

// Get the bounding rectangle of the element you want to click on
var rect = elementToClick.getBoundingClientRect();

// Calculate the coordinates of the point you want to click relative to the top-left corner of the element
var offsetX = 10; // adjust the value of offsetX as needed
var offsetY = 20; // adjust the value of offsetY as needed
var pointX = rect.left + offsetX;
var pointY = rect.top + offsetY;

// Simulate a click on the point using the coordinates relative to the top-left corner of the viewport
var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true,
  'clientX': pointX,
  'clientY': pointY
});
document.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

```html
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Test Click </a>
<div id="my-element"> <a href="https://www.example.com"> <img src ="https://place-hold.it/300x300" /> </a>
```

But it still not working. can you help me how to achieve this or what is the mistake in my code

Comment: does this answer helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054864/4248328

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant Partially. i just don't want to detect the click but manipulate it too. anywhere clicked, a particular element/content/coordinate should be clicked